# Inserting data into a MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am having trouble inserting data into the database 'justrated'. Once the user has entered their business name it should create a new entry in the table 'businesses'. For some reason I cannot get it so that the data is entered in the table. Any advice is gladly appreciated.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<input type="text" name="BusinessName" method="POST">
<input type="Submit" value="submit" name="submit" method="POST">

</form>

<?php


if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "justrated");
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO businesses (BusinessName)
VALUES ('".$_POST['BusinessName']."' )";
    mysql_query($sql);
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to learn [html form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). And don't mix `mysql and mysqli`

Comment: You can't use `mysql_query()` when you're using `mysqli`.

Comment: @Saty What's wrong with his form?

Comment: @Barmar check `method` in input type `<input type="text" name="BusinessName" method="POST">
`

Comment: possible duplicate of [inserting data into mysql database using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104271/inserting-data-into-mysql-database-using-php)

Comment: Read about prepared statements and SQL injections too.

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is that `$_POST['BusinessName']` is empty because the form was submitted using a GET request, not a POST request. The `method=POST` attribute goes on the `<form>` element. Eg:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="BusinessName">
  <input type="Submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Also, you should escape the data properly before you insert it into the database:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO businesses (BusinessName)
VALUES ('" . $conn->real_escape_string ($_POST['BusinessName']) . "' )";
```

Furthermore, in these two lines:

```
mysql_query($sql);
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

you try to execute the same query twice using both the MySQL and MySQLi extension. You should remove the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<form method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="BusinessName">
    <input type="Submit" value="submit" name="submit" >

    </form>
```

Php:
Use

```
$conn->query($sql); not mysql_query()
```

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for `mysqli_query`. He already has `$conn->query($sql)`, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```
<form method="post" action="test1.php">
<input type="text" name="BusinessName" >
<input type="Submit" value="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    //create connection 
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "justrated");
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO businesses (`BusinessName`)
        VALUES ('".$_POST['BusinessName']."' )";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Don't mix the `mysql` & `mysqli`....

Answer (score 0):

hello please check this one i hope this working for you

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO businesses (`BusinessName`)
        VALUES ('".$_POST['BusinessName']."' )";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```