# How to update database table using PHP Code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this following PHP that it will insert data from excel to database, but it won't update it.

Please guide me how to make it done? that If I change something, then it will update into database table rows too.

```
foreach($dataArr as $val){
$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO employees SET fname = '" . $db->escape($val['1']) . "', lname = '" . $db->escape($val['2']) . "', email = '" . $db->escape($val['3']) . "', phone = '" . $db->escape($val['4']) . "', company = '" . $db->escape($val['5']) . "'");
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, google `database update`. It is not rocket science.

Comment: I did, I couldn't make it. I'm new in PHP. I highly appreciate if you help me thanks

Comment: Refer to *any* tutorial on PHP/MySQL.  You currently have an `INSERT` statement, you're looking for an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Use `UPDATE` keyword

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inserting data into mysql database using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104271/inserting-data-into-mysql-database-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
INSERT INTO employees
```

with

```
UPDATE employees
```

**[Update Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)**

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not insert use update

```
$query = $db->query("Update employees SET fname = '" . $db->escape($val['1']) . "', lname = '" . $db->escape($val['2']) . "', email = '" . $db->escape($val['3']) . "', phone = '" . $db->escape($val['4']) . "', company = '" . $db->escape($val['5']) . "'" [WHERE where_condition]);
}
```

Comment: I got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'where' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'    for this line: foreach($dataArr as $val){

Comment: u should change [WHERE where_condition] like where id=$id

Comment: do you have id?